# How to calculate a solid angle defined by a point and a polygon?

Tags: geometry, angle

Let's define a point `O` with coordinates `Xo, Yo, Zo` and a polygon `ABCD` with coordinates `(Xa,Ya,Za), (Xb,Yb,Zb), (Xc,Yc,Zc), (Xd,Yd,Z)`

What is the most usual algorithmic way to compute the solid angle `Ω` defined by the polyhedron `ABCDO`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather simple method is to divide this pyramid into two tetrahedrons (for example, with common diagonal AC, if `ABCD` is convex), then calculate solid angle for each tetrahedron

```
Ω  = 2 * ArcTan(Dot(u1 X u2, u3) /(1 + Dot(u2,u3) + Dot(u1,u2) + Dot(u1,u3)))
```

where `u1, u2, u3` - normalized (unit) vectors from `O` to `A, B, C` point (for 1st tetrahedron)

Look at the possible issues of this approach in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron)

Comment: is this a mistake? `Dot(u1 X u2, u3)` what do you mean u1 X u2, u3   Thanks

Comment: This is 'mixed product' - vector product of u1 and u2, then dot product of result with u3  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product