# Calculate solid angle of polygon numerically

Tags: computational-geometry, numeric, angle

Suppose we have a polygon with coordinates `((x1, y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), (x3,y3, z3), ...)` and a point with coordinates `(x0, y0,z0)`

Is there any numerical method to calculate solid angle of polygon about the point? Are there any modules in python to calculate it?

I saw this question: [How to calculate a solid angle defined by a point and a polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655615/how-to-calculate-a-solid-angle-defined-by-a-point-and-a-polygon) but it seems to be about a polygon of 4 points.

Comment: You can triangulate the polygon, then project the vertices to a sphere centered at the point and accumulate the solid angles of the spherical triangles by Girard's theorem. I would not be surprised that there exists a generalization of the shoelace formula to spherical triangles, that would dispense you with triangulation, but I don't know it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess